# Using acts_as_list and in_place_editing at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins

I have a rails project where the the view displays a list of items.  I use acts_as_list to make the list DnD orderable and in_place_editing on each item to, well, edit it.

My problem is that when I DnD the items around, the item I drag automagically becomes editable when I drop it.  Any tips on how I can avoid that behavior.

Ideally, I'd like to make it editable by clicking a small icon next to the item, but I don't know how to make that work with this plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the element you are dragging has a listener on mouseup that begins the edit. You can specify an :external_control in the options hash if you want a different element to trigger the edit.

```
<div id="<%= dom_id(@obj) -%>">
  <span><%= @obj.to_s -%></span>
  <img id="<%= dom_id(@obj, :edit) -%>" src="edit_handle.png"/>
</div>
<%= in_place_editor(dom_id(@obj), :external_control => dom_id(@obj, :edit)) %>
<%= draggable_element(dom_id(@obj)) %>
```

Comment: That seems to only be part of it.  Adding the :external_control makes another element trigger it along with clicking the actual text.  Is it supposed to disable the effect of clicking the original text to make it editable?